# Search Interface opens a new Activity when search

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I am trying to use the Search Manager from Android.

In fact, I have an activity where I am calling

```
 onSearchRequested()
```

Then, I am using in the same activity this function to get the search string:

```
 // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
```

The problem is the next: When i am clicking to the search button, I am opening a new activity and i would like to stay on the same and do some searches. So, my goal is to avoid the new activity opening when I click to the search button.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution consists to reuse the developpers example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

The important thing is to create 2 activities, one for searches and one other for displaying the results.

In the manifest, use this code:

```
<application ... >
<!-- this is the searchable activity; it performs searches -->
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>

<!-- this activity enables the search dialog to initiate searches
     in the SearchableActivity -->
<activity android:name=".OtherActivity" ... >
    <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
</activity>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use in Manifest

```
<activity android:name="BrowseItems" android:label="@string/browseitems"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/itemsearchable" />
</activity>
```